# Implement a Waiting Loader in android

Tags: android, android-activity, progress, loader

I am New to andorid. I want to implement a waiting loader globally  so that i can implement in different another activity. Kindly provide me solution how can i do this with andorid studio.

I hope, you people can provide me any demo source code and Link for getting knowledge for the same.

Thanks,
Supriya Pandey

Comment: where your approach ?

Comment: Do you finished your google search?

Comment: I want to show in my application globally so that where i need, i just call that method with its arguments.

Comment: I did not get a knowledge from google, I hope you people help me.

Comment: @SupriyaPandey You can get a lot of resource by google search. Go through it. then you could get idea. If you've doubt in library or source, asked in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing any loader in context with the current activity. It will be a much better option.

It your activity you can use this:

```
  final static int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 1;

  ProgressDialog dialog;

  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
     switch(id){
     case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Whatever you want to tell them.");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true); // if you want people to be able to cancel the download
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
           @Override
           public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
           {
               **** cleanup.  Not needed if not cancelable ****
           }});
        return dialog;
     default:
        return null;
     }
```

To dismiss the dialog, simply call:

```
  dialog.dismiss();
```